# Spring social - facebook - validate if user uploaded photo

Tags: spring, facebook, facebook-graph-api, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I'm using Spring Social and I create the Facebook Connection, I'm able to retrieve user's profile picture, but in case the user doesn't have a profile picture the result is default facebook user profile picture. How to determine if user has a uploaded photo ?

```
Facebook facebookApi = (Facebook) connection.getApi();
facebookApi.userOperations().getUserProfileImage(250, 250);
```

I looked for every available methods and there is nothing nor any data which allow me to determine this.

How to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have connection, you can upload image from url:

`String imagUrl = connection.getImageUrl();
URL url = new URL(imagUrl);
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);`

To change dimension of uploaded image you can use "type"  `imagUrl += "?type=large";`